# How do I get a specific variable from another file if it is not defined in the constructor?

Tags: python, function, class

I have the following 2 programs below and I want to use from cells.py self.display = 'X' to only get the 'X' value in the second file by any means printed so therefore in the second file I get 'X' by using cells.py somehow.
Thanks very much in advance!

cells.py

```
class Start:
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = 'X'

    def step(self, game):
        pass
```

other.py

```
from cells import (
    Start,
    End,
    Air,
    Wall,
    Fire,
    Water,
    Teleport
)
print(Air)
```

Comment: create an instance, then access its `.display` attribute? What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I swear I didn't plagiarize you even though my answer started with the same exact sentence. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the class, then access its `display` attribute.

```
s = Start()
print(s.display)
```

The fact that it's from another file doesn't change how you use classes.